# Extract elements in xml to rows in select statement

Tags: sql, xml, xquery-sql

I have got xml column in my sql server 2008 database. XML sample in each row of my table

```
<document>
 <part1>
   <listitem>val1</listitem>
   <listitem>val2</listitem>
   <listitem>val3</listitem>
 </part1>
 <part2>
   <listitem>val4</listitem>
 </part2>
</document>
```

I would like to select all  elements from all rows. From sample above I should get four rows with listitem value.

**The answer is**

```
select x.nd.value ('(.)[1]', 'varchar(250)') as ValuesFromXml
from TableWithXmlColumn t cross apply t.XmlContent.nodes (
'//listitem') x(nd);
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select Col.value('.', 'varchar(20)') 
from yourtable 
cross apply XmlColumn.nodes('//listitem') as NewTable(Col)
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!